# Cannot call method with mocha

Tags: solidity, web3js, mocha

I am running some test in my first smart contract called `Inbox.sol`.
I Want to call the method `.message` in order to see if it is equal to the default variable I use when I deploy the contract with web3.

My **Inbox.sol** code

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.12;

contract Inbox {
    string public message;

    function initialInbox(string memory initialMessage) public {
        message = initialMessage;
    }

    function setMessage(string memory newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }
}
```

My **test** file with Mocha is:

```
let accounts
let inbox

beforeEach(async () => {
  // Get a list of all accounts
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
  // Use one of those account to deploy the contract
  inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
    .deploy({ data: bytecode, arguments: [INITIAL_ARGUMENT]})
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: GAS})
})

describe(('Inbox'), () => {
  it("has a default message", async () => {
    const message = await inbox.methods.message() // Returns a big object
    console.log(message)
    const messageCalled = await inbox.methods.message().call()
    console.log(messageCalled) // Returns nothing
    assert.strictEqual(message, INITIAL_ARGUMENT)
  })
})
```

Comment: Please add a constructor function if you wish to store an initial value to the 'message' variable.

Answer (score 0):

For the version that you are  using you should be adding a constructor to your contract:

```
contract Inbox {
    string public message;

    constructor(string memory initialMessage) public {
        message = initialMessage;
    }
```

since "message" is a public variable, solidity sets its getter, so you can call it `message()`